# Imageviews not centering when using layout_weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am trying to make a horizontal menu bar, however for some reason when I use weights they do not align horizontally, any suggestions?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottombuttonslayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listSlotBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listSlot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/list" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftArrorSlotBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".20" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowSlot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playSlotBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".20" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playSlot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/playing" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rightArrowSlotBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".20" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowSlot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/right_arrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what it looks like, they are aligning vertically. not horizontally:

[image]

**EDIT**

This is following the first suggestion:

[image]

Comment: They will not align horizontally because `android:layout_gravity="center"` will only work in vertical direction for a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout` (and vice versa for a vertically oriented one). Did you try adding `android:gravity="center"` on the nested LinearLayouts in stead? Alternatively, you can always exchange them for something like a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, which will give you some more control over positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Each image view needs `android:gravity="center"`.

You are centering the containing linearlayouts... I don't understand why you are using all of them...  you should use one, like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/bottombuttonslayout" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="58dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" > 
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/listSlot" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" 
        android:background="@drawable/list"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowSlot" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" 
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/playSlot" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" 
        android:background="@drawable/playing"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowSlot" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" 
        android:background="@drawable/right_arrow"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Following what you provided it compiled to what is above. I will add the image to my post.

Comment: Made a mistake.  All the widths for the imageviews need to be set to "0dp".  And I'm uncertain if you should keep `android:adjustViewBounds="false"` or set it to true... as a last resort, revert to what you had, but add `android:gravity="center"` to each imageview.

Comment: Okay well I tried all that was mentioned and nothing worked. The first part didn't change anything strangely and reusing my old code with your suggestion just kept it the way it was displayed in my first image. Very confusing. It's centered vertically but not horizontally .